# how to make submenus of navigation bar on right side and on left side on minimization of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Submenus on rights side is easily possible in navigation bar but on minimization of screen how to make submenus turn automatically on left side?

Comment: you can use css media queries

Comment: can you please share me the code for that!

Comment: Please can you give your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #mainmenu{
        float: right;
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" align="right">  
  <ul id="mainmenu" class="nav nav-tabs">   
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle navbar-right" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
      </ul>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .submenu {
        /*This and this style when window-width is greater than 500px*/
    }
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .submenu {
        /*This and this style when window-width is less than 500px*/
    }
    }
```

Please add your current style and html-code for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
nav li {
  float: right;
}

/*The max width the that the screen has to be for this rule to apply*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
  nav li {
    float: left;
  }
}
```